How to implement a mobile_no to be passed inorder to access tokens and not the default username and password
I'm not using password, by default simplejwt requires a default user so it prompts me for username, password and mobile_no - but I only want to user mobile no.
I tried to override the TokenObtainpairSerializer - but to no success

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Ok - what's the best way to implement a passwordless authentication, by using mobile number, and then get access and refresh tokens
